# Cannot connect with either wireless cards Qualcomm Athereos QCA6174 or Wilocity Wil6200

Tags: networking, drivers, atheros

I have Ubuntu 16.4 on Asus Zenith. Two wireless adapters haven't worked since day 1. I have:

Qualcomm Athereos QCA6174 801.11ac

Wilocity Wil6200  802.11ad

Below find some commands I ran for analysis:

```
joe@joeslinux:~$ sudo rfkill list
[sudo] password for joe: 
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: phy1: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

joe@joeslinux:~$ sudo lshw -class network
  *-network               
       description: Wireless interface
       product: QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlp3s0
       version: 32
       serial: e0:4f:43:70:4f:cc
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath10k_pci driverversion=4.4.0-116-generic firmware=WLAN.RM.2.0-00180-QCARMSWPZ-1 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
       resources: irq:84 memory:ef400000-ef5fffff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wil6200 802.11ad Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Wilocity Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: wlp4s0
       version: 02
       serial: dc:ef:ca:e5:cc:80
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=wil6210 driverversion=4.4.0-116-generic firmware=55 latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:79 memory:ef200000-ef3fffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: I211 Gigabit Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
       logical name: enp5s0
       version: 03
       serial: 10:7b:44:92:0d:8d
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi msix pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=igb driverversion=5.3.0-k duplex=full firmware=0. 6-1 ip=192.168.1.34 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:24 memory:ef700000-ef71ffff ioport:7000(size=32) memory:ef720000-ef723fff
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Ethernet controller
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
       version: 02
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress pm msix msi vpd bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:ef040000-ef04ffff memory:ef050000-ef050fff memory:eec00000-eeffffff memory:ef000000-ef03ffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 1
       bus info: usb@7:2.2
       logical name: eth0
       serial: 4a:74:6e:bb:cc:b2
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ipheth link=no multicast=yes

joe@joeslinux:~$ lsusb
Bus 008 Device 002: ID 2109:0812 VIA Labs, Inc. VL812 Hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 006: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 007 Device 003: ID 413c:a503 Dell Computer Corp. 
Bus 007 Device 005: ID 24f0:0140  
Bus 007 Device 004: ID 05ac:12a0 Apple, Inc. iPhone 4S
Bus 007 Device 002: ID 2109:2812 VIA Labs, Inc. VL812 Hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0b05:1868 ASUSTek Computer, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0b05:1867 ASUSTek Computer, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub



joe@joeslinux:~$ dmesg | grep "ath"
[    5.770386] md: multipath personality registered for level -4
[   18.715195] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: pci irq msi interrupts 1 irq_mode 0 reset_mode 0
[   18.998860] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/cal-pci-0000:03:00.0.bin failed with error -2
[   19.010328] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/firmware-5.bin failed with error -2
[   19.010331] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: could not fetch firmware file 'ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/firmware-5.bin': -2
[   21.558118] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: qca6174 hw3.2 (0x05030000, 0x00340aff sub 1043:8752) fw WLAN.RM.2.0-00180-QCARMSWPZ-1 fwapi 4 bdapi 2 htt-ver 3.26 wmi-op 4 htt-op 3 cal otp max-sta 32 raw 0 hwcrypto 1 features wowlan,ignore-otp,no-4addr-pad
[   21.558122] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: debug 0 debugfs 1 tracing 1 dfs 0 testmode 0
[   21.633953] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x69
[   21.633955] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a direct regpair map
[   21.633956] ath: Country alpha2 being used: 00
[   21.633957] ath: Regpair used: 0x69
[   21.692916] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: renamed from wlan0



joe@joeslinux:~$ dmesg | grep "wil"
[   18.132238] wil6210 0000:04:00.0: wil6210 device found [1ae9:0310] (rev 2)
[   18.132469] wil6210 0000:04:00.0 (unnamed net_device) (uninitialized): CSR at [mem 0xef200000-0xef3fffff 64bit] -> 0xffffc90007c00000
[   18.132473] wil6210 0000:04:00.0 (unnamed net_device) (uninitialized): Board hardware is Sparrow B0
[   18.185301] wil6210 0000:04:00.0 (unnamed net_device) (uninitialized): Boot Loader struct v2: MAC = dc:ef:ca:e5:cc:80 RF = 0x0000 (status 0x0000) bband = 0x00000000
[   18.185304] wil6210 0000:04:00.0 (unnamed net_device) (uninitialized): Boot Loader build 255.255.0.6836
[   18.992003] wil6210 0000:04:00.0 wlp4s0: renamed from wlan0
[   30.063052] wil6210 0000:04:00.0 wlp4s0: Boot Loader struct v2: MAC = dc:ef:ca:e5:cc:80 RF = 0x0000 (status 0x0000) bband = 0x00000000
[   30.063054] wil6210 0000:04:00.0 wlp4s0: Boot Loader build 255.255.0.6836
[   30.063057] wil6210 0000:04:00.0 wlp4s0: Use firmware <wil6210.fw> + board <wil6210.brd>
[   30.135395] wil6210 0000:04:00.0 wlp4s0: set ITR_TX_CNT_TRSH = 500 usec
[   30.135398] wil6210 0000:04:00.0 wlp4s0: set ITR_TX_IDL_CNT_TRSH = 13 usec
[   30.135400] wil6210 0000:04:00.0 wlp4s0: set ITR_RX_CNT_TRSH = 500 usec
[   30.135402] wil6210 0000:04:00.0 wlp4s0: set ITR_RX_IDL_CNT_TRSH = 13 usec
[   30.153435] wil6210 0000:04:00.0 wlp4s0: Received "Rx buffer is in risk of overflow" interrupt
[   30.153438] wil6210 0000:04:00.0 wlp4s0: Got Rx interrupt while in reset
[   30.153509] wil6210 0000:04:00.0 wlp4s0: FW ver. 55; MAC dc:ef:ca:e5:cc:80; 0 MID's
[   30.153523] wil6210 0000:04:00.0 wlp4s0: FW ready after 16 ms. HW version 0x00000001
[   30.153868] wil6210 0000:04:00.0 wlp4s0: Received "Rx buffer is in risk of overflow" interrupt
[   30.153870] wil6210 0000:04:00.0 wlp4s0: Got Rx interrupt while stopping interface


joe@joeslinux:~$ dmesg | grep -i firmware
[    0.272801] [Firmware Bug]: AMD-Vi: IOAPIC[130] not in IVRS table
[    0.724458] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    0.794594] acpi PNP0A08:01: [Firmware Info]: MMCONFIG for domain 0000 [bus 00-7f] only partially covers this bridge
[   18.998860] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/cal-pci-0000:03:00.0.bin failed with error -2
[   19.010328] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/firmware-5.bin failed with error -2
[   19.010331] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: could not fetch firmware file 'ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/firmware-5.bin': -2
[   30.063057] wil6210 0000:04:00.0 wlp4s0: Use firmware <wil6210.fw> + board <wil6210.brd>
```

Help and suggestions appreciated. I'm still on the learning curve.
I am using a wired adapter currently, computer sits next to the router.
A mini usb dongle-type adapter works, but doesn't have the range to connect even 15 ft (3m) away :(
Joe

Edit:

Results of uname -a

```
joe@joeslinux:~$ uname -a
Linux joeslinux 4.4.0-116-generic #140-Ubuntu SMP Mon Feb 12 21:23:04 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Please add the results of `uname -a` to your question.

Comment: Thank you for your interest. uname -a is       joe@joeslinux:~$ uname -a
Linux joeslinux 4.4.0-116-generic #140-Ubuntu SMP Mon Feb 12 21:23:04 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 0):

I'm also on a an Asus Zenith board and wireless works on Ubuntu 18.04 FYI

It may be that you need Ubuntu 18.04's 4.15+ Kernel which can be found here:

http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.15.18/

Although you may also need an updated QCA6174 firmware which is in Ubuntu 18.04 so you may need to upgrade anyway.

Comment: Tek's on 18.04, and although it doesn't work on 16.04 it works his Asus Zenith board on 18.04. It's OK to post that.

Comment: That is really Linux Kernel `4.15.18` the Ubuntu equivalent would be something like `4.15.0-33`

Comment: Thank you @Tek,
Then as fast as the problem appeared, it disappeared. I bight the bullet to upgrade to 18.04, I'll remember this.